# Argue informally that $\int_{γ}\frac{1}{z^2}dz=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, complex-integration

Let $γ$ be a simple closed curve contenting $0$ Argue informally that $\int_{γ}\frac{1}{z^2}dz=0$

I think this is simple if the integral is equal to $0$ then the antiderivative $-\frac{1}{z}$ would be holomorphic on $0$ and that's a contradiction.

My question is if I couldn't find the antiderivative how could I justify that the integral wouldn't be $0$?

Comment: Did you mean to say, "argue informally that $\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z^2}dz\color{red}{\neq}0$"?

Comment: No i think this is correct argue means the opposite, if i where to put $\neq $ i would write prove.

Comment: No, "argue" means "give an argument supporting".  The defense argues that the accused is innocent, the prosecution argues that he's guilty.

Comment: oo ok now that makes sense thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote that “if the integral is equal to $0$ then the antiderivative $−\frac1z$ would be holomorphic on $0$ and that's a contradiction”. There are lots of problems here. The function $z\mapsto-\frac1z$ *is* holomorphic on $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$; there is no “if” here. And, since $z\mapsto\frac1{z^2}$ has an antiderivative on $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$, its integral along any closed path is $0$.

And if you can't find an antiderivative of a function $f$, then it still may well be true that $\int_\gamma f=0$ for any closed path $\gamma$.

Comment: @user When I wrote $z\mapsto\frac1z$, what I had in mind was that the domain would be $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: @user It's done.

Comment: The theorem doesn't say that if the integral of the closed curve is $0$ then the antiderivative would be holomorphic on the set $A$ where A is the interior of that curve? Since $0$ is not included I thought that would be a contradiction. Any hints so I can give a proper explanation?

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't know which is the statement for which you want to provide a proper explanation.

Comment: Let $γ$ be a simple closed curve contenting $0$ prove that $ \int_{γ}\frac{1}{z^2}dz\neq 0 $

Comment: I don't know the meaning of contenting $0$.

Comment: $0$ is in the interior of the curve

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123359/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-petros-k).